# Prove or disprove $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-a_{j}|^2|b_{ij}|^2\le \cdots$

Tags: inequality

> let $a_{i},b_{ij}\in C,i=1,2,\cdots,n,j=1,2,\cdots,n$,prove or disprove
> $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-a_{j}|^2|b_{ij}|^2\le 2(|a_{1}|^2+|a_{2}|^2+\cdots+|a_{n}|^2)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|b_{ij}|^2$$

This problem is from when deal follow this problem
$$||AB-BA||_{F}\le\sqrt{2}||A||_{F}||B||_{F}$$
where $A,B\in M_{n}(C)$

the reslut is from this paper:[link](http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/preprint/2008/PREPRINT_05.pdf)

My try: consider this follow  special case
$$A=diag{(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})},B=(b_{ij})_{n\times n}$$
then
$$AB-BA=diag(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})B-Bdiag(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})=(a_{i}-a_{j})b_{ij}$$
so
$$||AB-BA||^2_{F}=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|a_{i}-a_{j}|^2|b_{ij}|^2\le 2(|a_{1}|^2+|a_{2}|^2+\cdots+|a_{n}|^2)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|b_{ij}|^2$$

Now Singular value decomposition,
prove $A=Udiag(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})V$

By done

this my wrong? Thank you

It seem is true,because $$|a_{i}-a_{j}|^2=a^2_{i}+a^2_{j}-2a_{i}a_{j}\le a^2_{i}+a^2_{j}?$$

if this is true.Now I have easy method to solve this problem

Thank you

Comment: What is $C$?${}$

Comment: Hello,it mean complex  field

Comment: $C$ is the set of complex numbers, right?  If $a_i \in C$, then the expression $2(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \ldots + a_n^2)$ is not necessarily real, so the "$\le$" sign is dubious.

Comment: @1950RobertLewis,I have edit.Thank you

Comment: Much better!  Glad to help out!  *Now* the question makes sense!  Cheers!

Comment: @1950RobertLewis，Cheers! HaHa